# Parsing JSON in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In my controller I am fetching the json by using $http.get like this:

```
$http.get('http://webapp-app4car.rhcloud.com/product/feed.json').success(function(data)
```

now data is a JSON and I want to get the value corresponding to JSON key. My key is stored in a variable "key". How can I access the value ? **data.key** is not working as key is a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use object as arrays in javascript, try:

```
data[key];
```

Comment: You mean you use the same syntax you'd use for an array. I strongly suspect `data` is not an array.

Comment: @DavidKnipe please learn about how bracket notation works in JavaScript before making incorrect remarks about it.

Comment: thanks, it is working and it is an object not an array @DavidKnipe

Comment: @Benjamin Please enlighten us.

Comment: @DavidKnipe In JavaScript you have two ways to access object properties. You can use the normal dot notation `object.key` and bracket notation `object["key"]` - in the second way (called bracket form) you access object keys by a dynamic string - so for example you can (but probably shouldn't) do something like: `var x = {hello:"World"}; x["hell"+"o"]` to get `"World"`. In fact, even arrays are objects in JavaScript and even (in language specification, not practice) array keys are just string object keys that are coercible to UInt32 (arr["2"] and arr[2] are the same) http://es5.github.io/#x15.4

Comment: @Benjamin I agree. But I don't see how any of this contradicts what I said. All arrays are objects, but not all objects are arrays.

Comment: You said "I strongly suspect `data` is not an array' - which I thought implies that you think this is an incorrect approach since "`data` is not an array and this wouldn't work with objects". I apologize if I understood incorrectly - I think we're in agreement now.

Answer (score 1):

Use subscript notation.

```
data["key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create a fiddle for the same. Just a hunch, that your data is an array and hence you need to do something like data[0].key